# \setmathfont no longer working in TeXShop in macOS Monterey

Tags: fonts, mathspec

I got a new computer that came with Monterey, and I restored everything from a backup of my previous computer, which had Catalina (10.5.7), so every font and every setting should have remained intact.

However, MacTeX no longer changes the math font to whatever is set in the `\setmathfont` command; it leaves the font intact regardless of that command. It does change the main font to whatever is set in the `\setmainfont` command, though, which is odd.

I've checked that the font is installed (it is). My MacTeX version is 2015 (!).

I'm using the `mathspec` package and compiling in XeLaTeX.

Edit: Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX},Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{Calluna}
\setsansfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX},Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Calluna}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Arabic=Regular,Uppercase=Plain,Lowercase=Plain,Numbers={Lining,Monospaced}]{Calluna}

\newcommand*{\eq}[1]{\begin{eqnarray}#1\end{eqnarray}}

\begin{document}\sloppy

\eq{E & = & \frac{E_0}{\sqrt{\rho}}\,e^{\pm i\left(k\rho-\omega t\right)}\nonumber}

\vfill

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: [Do *not* use eqnarray.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001) [Avoid eqnarray!](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/tex/displays.html) [Avoid eqnarray!](https://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/eqnarray-align-environment/) [Avoid eqnarray!](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/)

Comment: Off-topic: Since you load `amssymb`, there can be no sane reason for loading `latex-sym` as well. Since `amsymb` loads `amsfonts` automatically, there is no need for `\usepackage{amsfonts}`. Unless you most recently updated your TeX distribution ten or more years ago, there can be no reason for loading `epstopdf` either. Do load `graphicx` instead of `graphics`, though. And what's with `\vfill`?

Comment: TeXshop does not actually compile anything; it is "just" a front-end to a TeX distribution. In your case, this TeX distribution will almost certainly be MacTeX, which is -- for all practical purposes -- TeXLive plus a MacOS-specific GUI. Which version of MacTeX did you migrate from your old to your new computer? The current version of MacTeX is MacTeX2021; are you willing to download and install it? BTW, the current version of TeXshop is 4.68.

Comment: no one can debug "does not respect" what error did you get? Reduce your example removing every package that you can remove while still showing the problem then show the log file of the resulting run.

Comment: @Mico Re packages, thanks. Re `\vfill`, it ensures the text isn’t centred vertically on the page if it isn’t enough to fill the whole page. Re MacTeX, I think it was 2021, probably, since that’s when I last updated things. Maybe not, though. Will check.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah, sorry, I was a bit fed up with things at that point. Should have been clearer. Have edited for clarification.

Comment: @Mico It’s 2015 (!).

Comment: latex never vertically centres text pages so the vfill at the end isn't doing anything useful

Comment: @Rain - Do give yourself a treat and update your TeX distribution to MacTeX2021. And do please verify for yourself that `\vfill` does nothing at all in the test document you provided (except, of course, look mighty quaint).

Comment: You still have not shown a log. I don't hav ethe font so using your test file I get `! Package fontspec Error: The font "Calluna" cannot be found.`  If I use a file in texlive, say `TeX Gyre Termes` in place of all three `Calluna` I get  no error but most of the math is in computer modern. I'd use unicode-math package if I wanted opentype math, but someone may be able to help with mathspec if you provide an example that shows the problem using available fonts.

Comment: Ah, but it does centre images. And who am I to know beforehand whether or not my document will end with an image or not?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As for the font, I’m away from my computer at the moment, but aren’t you having the same problem as me? It compiles, but the maths isn’t in the chosen font, it’s in bloody Computer Modern.